# How to replicate youtube "video card". I cant make the user icon to take 3 rows. Not sure if I should do it with bootstrap or flex or what

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox

[This is the layout I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plj94.png)

```
<section>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" style="background-color: rgb(163, 163, 163)">
        <!-- VIDEO THUMBNAIL -->
        <a mat-list-item routerLink=''>
            <img class="" src="../../assets/img/thumbnails/colibri.jpg" alt="colibri" style="max-width:100%;">
        </a>
        <!-- Uploaders user image -->
        <a mat-list-item>
            <img src="../../assets/img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="border-radius: 50%; width:40px;">
        </a>
        <!-- video heading and information -->
        <h2>Animals in rainforest</h2>
        <a href="">Content Creator</a>
        <p>2,1 milj. views · 2 years ago</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### I cant make the avatar icon to take three rows on the left

the avatar icon, h2, content creator and information are just stacked on top of each other.
(sorry if the post is confusing this is my first time posting in stack overflow).
best regards Angular developer from Finland

Comment: Please share what you have tried and any docs/standards stating it should produce the result you expect. Ideally, you should create a [mcve]. Without knowing what styles already apply in the page, it is difficult to provide/test any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="media">
        <img src="..." class="mr-3" style="max-width: 80px" alt="...">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0">Animals in rainforest</h5>
          <a href="">Content Creator</a>
          <p>2,1 milj. views · 2 years ago</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... should do it. Here's a demo:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Colibri-thalassinus-001-edit.jpg" alt="colibri">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="media">
            <img src="https://img.stackshare.io/service/1927/so-icon.png" class="mr-3" style="max-width: 80px" alt="...">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h5 class="mt-0">Animals in rainforest</h5>
              <a href="">Content Creator</a>
              <p>2,1 milj. views · 2 years ago</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Colibri-thalassinus-001-edit.jpg" alt="colibri">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="media">
            <img src="https://img.stackshare.io/service/1927/so-icon.png" class="mr-3" style="max-width: 80px" alt="...">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h5 class="mt-0">Animals in rainforest</h5>
              <a href="">Content Creator</a>
              <p>2,1 milj. views · 2 years ago</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Colibri-thalassinus-001-edit.jpg" alt="colibri">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="media">
            <img src="https://img.stackshare.io/service/1927/so-icon.png" class="mr-3" style="max-width: 80px" alt="...">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h5 class="mt-0">Animals in rainforest</h5>
              <a href="">Content Creator</a>
              <p>2,1 milj. views · 2 years ago</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Colibri-thalassinus-001-edit.jpg" alt="colibri">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="media">
            <img src="https://img.stackshare.io/service/1927/so-icon.png" class="mr-3" style="max-width: 80px" alt="...">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h5 class="mt-0">Animals in rainforest</h5>
              <a href="">Content Creator</a>
              <p>2,1 milj. views · 2 years ago</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Bootstrap docs:

- [media object](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/media-object/)
- [cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/)
- [grid layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)
- [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/)